# Logical operator 'OR' in Python not working as intended?

Tags: python, logical-operators, logical-or

I don't understand why the "or" operator is not working as intended in this case.

Here is the code:

```py
fuel = input()
liters = float(input())

if fuel != 'Gas' or fuel != 'Diesel' or fuel != 'Gasoline':
    print('Invalid fuel!')
else:
    if liters >= 25:
        if fuel == 'Gas' or fuel == 'Diesel' or fuel == 'Gasoline':
            print(f'You have enough {fuel.lower()}.')
    elif liters < 25:
        if fuel == 'Gas' or fuel == 'Diesel' or fuel == 'Gasoline':
            print(f'Fill your tank with {fuel.lower()}!')
```

Input:

```
Gas
25
```

Output:
`Invalid fuel`

The output should be `You have enough gas.`

When I change the operator to "and", the code works fine.

```py
if fuel != 'Gas' and fuel != 'Diesel' and fuel != 'Gasoline':
    print('Invalid fuel!')
```

Could someone please explain why is this happening?

Comment: Remember, when using `or`, only one of the operands needs to be `True` for the entire expression to evaluate to `True`. So, `fuel != 'Gas'` will be `False`, but `fuel != 'Diesel'` will be `True`. The condition `fuel != 'Gasoline'` will also be `True`, but it doesn't need to be evaluated due to short-circuiting, since we've already found something that's `True`. In any case, the whole expression will always be `True`. In order for it to be `False`, `fuel` would have to be equal to `'Gas'`, `'Diesel'` and `'Gasoline'` all at the same time, which of course can never be the case.

Comment: Thank you @PaulM. 
I was so concentrated in only the first part of the statement that I completely ignored the rest of it. 
Great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

That is not the place for the `or` operator, you should be using `and` in that case.

By using the `or` operator there, you are saying that as long as `fuel` is not one of `Diesel`, `Gas` or `Gasoline`, it should output `Invalid fuel`. Since `fuel` is `Gas`, then it cannot be `Diesel`, or `Gasoline`, therefore the if statement will yield `True` and will print  `Invalid fuel`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!
I don't know how I missed that...
I'm shocked!

Answer (score 2):

With `fuel = 'Gas'`, this:

```
if fuel != 'Gas' or fuel != 'Diesel' or fuel != 'Gasoline':
```

evaluates to:

```
if False or True or True:
```

which is the same as:

```
if True:
```

What you need is in fact `and`, as you have discovered:

```
if fuel != 'Gas' and fuel != 'Diesel' and fuel != 'Gasoline':
```

or, better, use [sets](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) for speed of lookups and brevity, assigning it to a variable to avoid repeating yourself:

```
allowed_fuels = set(['Gas', 'Diesel', 'Gasoline'])
if fuel not in allowed_fuels:
    print(f'Invalid fuel: {fuel}')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!
I totally ignored the fact that when fuel is gas is not equal to diesel or gasoline, then this is a True statement.